# OS version 4.4 (KitKat) and 5 (Lollipop) onVisibilityChanged Listener Not Firing

Tags: android, view, visibility

I have looked online for an answer to this, but have not found the root cause of this issue.

I have an application with a view, that listens in on [onVisibilityChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#onVisibilityChanged(android.view.View,%20int)) and [onWindowVisibilityChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onWindowVisibilityChanged(int)). What I have noticed is that on Android devices with either KitKat (API 19) or Lollipop (API 22), when the view gets attached to the main layout, onVisibilityChanged is never fired, only onWindowVisibilityChanged.

I am guessing this issue originates with a native API change that occurred from KitKat up to Lollipop, but have not found any documentation or reference to this. When I checked my application on Marshmallow (API 23), it did not happen.

I would just like to know if this is a known issue or if there is some sort of way to fix this behavior.

Thanks.

Comment: post your code snippet

Comment: @PembaTamang - Cannot post code snippet as it is intricate code with company logic. In respect to the View classes, the two listeners, onVisibilityChanged and onWindowVisibilityChanged are implemented as is. They should be called normally (as happens in OS versions after 5.1).

Comment: could you de couple the business logic and post the code ??

Comment: its the only way you'll find a good answer

Comment: @PembaTamang - I understand what you are saying, but in regards to the visibility listeners, they are implemented vanilla wise. There is no special logic there. Just overriding the methods from the parent view class. There should not be an issue if they are working on newer operating system versions.

Comment: are you using androidx dependencies ?? those are causing a lot of problem these days

Comment: @PembaTamang - Nope.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your problem sorry

Comment: can you use `onAttachedToWindow` and `onDetachedFromWindow` instead of that methods?

Comment: @BAHMAN - Those two methods have a different behavior than onVisibilityChanged and onWindowVisibilityChanged, so no.

Comment: can you override `onWindowVisibilityChanged` and call `onVisibilityChanged` only on APIs that it don not get called automatically (19 and 22 as you say)?

Comment: what behavior do you need? maybe you can use other methods instead of these two

Comment: @BAHMAN - Please read my original post. The behavior I am looking for works on Android OS > 5, but not on 4.4 or 5. The methods themselves have not been deprecated and should work across all API levels.

Comment: There is no such known issue with these API versions. I have tested it on API 21(Emulator) and API 19(Emulator) and its working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the Android team did indeed change this behavior in Android 23 - Marshmallow. If you look at the source code for `View.java` in Android 23, you can see that they added a call to `onVisibilityChanged` inside of `dispatchAttachedToWindow`.

[Here is the commit to AOSP where this change happened](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/eb2b0af22c7b3fd1cc0297547b9f96c7976a7d59).

[Here is the diff for that change](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/eb2b0af22c7b3fd1cc0297547b9f96c7976a7d59%5E%21/core/java/android/view/View.java).

Given that you are unable to post your code, I cannot offer a better solution than to point you to the change.

If you are trying to track view attaches to the window, I would suggest the `onAttachedToWindow` API.

Note that the method that calls `onVisibilityChanged` in Android 23 is most likely `dispatchAttachedToWindow`. This method also calls `onAttachedToWindow`, so you could theoretically listen for this and check the visibility manually.

```
   // Override inside your custom view
   override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow()

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            // Check for visibility here, but note that onVisibilityChanged initially gets called with View.GONE
            // Unless the view is inside of a ViewGroup. See the source code for ViewRootImpl.java for more details.
        }
    }
```

Otherwise, you will need to special case your logic for Android 22 and below such that you listen to the `onWindowVisibilityChanged` more instead of `onVisibilityChanged`.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I was suspicious of. Major kudos!